# JPA Criteria Union: will be in JPA standard?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, union, criteria

JPA Criteria Union: will be in JPA standard soon? Union is important. For union, I have to use native SQL that I do not like. Multitenant does not support NATIVE SQL. Any proposal for supporting union in Criteria builder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UNION is totally an SQL construct, not object-based in any way, consequently I don't imagine it will added. BUT if you feel strongly enough about something you go to their mailing list
https://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists
and propose WHY it should be included, with examples of what is trying to be achieved (i.e a lot more than what you stated in this "question"). Clearly a JPA provider could already make implicit use of UNION in any SQL it issues based on the query the user makes.

I don't see what multitenant has to do with anything since that is not part of JPA either.

Comment: we try to avoid NATIVE SQL as much as possible to make application portable across all databases. It should be very easy to support UNION in JPA. I do not get it why it is not in the standard. The reason to support UNION is obvious, same as why UNION is supported in NATIVE SQL. JPA is just java API on the top of NATIVE SQL. EclipseLink JPQL supports union, and hope it will be in the Criteria API soon. Wondering if anyone can workaround UNION using Criteria API in eclipseLink.

Comment: All JPQL queries are for a specific entity type, "the reason to support UNION" to you may be obvious but isn't to many others. To present a case you have to present examples, with sample entities and the proposed JPQL syntax and what is the expected return, and what role it fulfils. Yes, I get the avoid native SQL part, but that isn't a reason in itself to put something into JPQL